# jQuery slideDown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making something like a dropdown menu on a website.Here is part of my code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#Q1").toggle(function(){
      $("#A1").slideUp()
    },function(){
      $("#A1").slideDown()
    });
  });
$("#A1").hide();
```

The element with the ID Q1 is a dt,and the one with ID A1 is a dd. I intend to toggle between showing A1 and hiding it by clicking on Q1.Initially, I don't want it shown,therefore I used the hide() method.

The problem I am having with this is that after the page is loaded, I have to first click Q1 twice to get A1 shown. After that,everything goes as planned(one click to trigger the animation).

Can anybody help me with this problem.Thank you.

Comment: Try inverting the "slideDown" and "slideUp"  positions

Comment: I was stupid not to have noticed that. It worked perfectly. Thank you.